# Scala how to replace an object in case class tree

Tags: scala

I have a tree built up of case classes, to simplify let's assume the following:

```
trait Traversable

abstract class Node extends Traversable
case class NodeTypeA(child1:Traversable, text:Leaf) extends Node
case class NodeTypeB(child1:Traversable, child2:Traversable) extends Node
case class SpecialType() extends Node

case class Leaf() extends Traversable
```

No I want to substitute all SpecialType objects in the tree with some other Traversable object I supply to the substitution function.

I made a solution that iterates through the tree and replaces occurrences of SpecialType like this:

```
def sub(tree: Traversable, substitude: Traversable) : Traversable = {
  tree match {
    case NodeTypeA(c1, text) => NodeTypeA(sub(c1, substitude), sub(text, substitude))
    case NodeTypeB(c1, c2) => NodeTypeB(sub(c1, substitude), sub(c2, substitude))
    case SpecialType() => substitude
    case other => other
  }
}
```

This works but requires me to have a case for each traversable type. Is there a way to make this more generic? In Scheme I would do a similar approach but since everything is a list in Scheme it is easy to rebuild everything in a generic way.

So what I am hoping for is something that looks like this:

```
t match {
  case SpecialType() => s

  case s:Traversable => s.type(s.children.all(sub(_, s)))

  case other => other
}
```

Is this or something similar to this possible in Scala?

Example:

```
sub(NodeTypeA(SpecialType(), Leaf()), NodeTypeB(Leaf(), Leaf()))
output: NodeTypeA(NodeTypeB(Leaf(), Leaf()), Leaf())
```

Comment: `case NodeTypeB(c1, c2) => NodeTypeA(sub(c1, s) sub(c2, s))` Is this a typo? Is `NodeTypeA` correct?

Comment: @krismath that is indeed a typo, should be fixed now.

Comment: I don't understand `sub(text, s)`. `sub` takes in two `Traversable`s. Is there another `sub` function?

Comment: Your posted solution still doesn't compile. Aside from the missing commas, `sub(text,s)` won't fly because `text` is not a `Traversable`.

Comment: @krismath there is just one sub function, but you can assume that all classes in the tree are of the traversable type. I just added the text field to signal that the different node types have different parameters. I edited it now, and added example for further clarification.

Comment: It's possible, using shapeless https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give each class knowledge of its own role in the substitution scheme.

```
trait Traversable {
  def sub(other: Traversable): Traversable = this
}

case class Leaf() extends Traversable
abstract class Node extends Traversable

case class NodeTypeA(child1:Traversable, text:Leaf) extends Node {
  override def sub(other:Traversable) = NodeTypeA(child1.sub(other), text)
}
case class NodeTypeB(child1:Traversable, child2:Traversable) extends Node {
  override def sub(other:Traversable) = NodeTypeB(child1.sub(other), child2.sub(other))
}
case class SpecialType() extends Node {
  override def sub(other:Traversable) = other
}

NodeTypeA(SpecialType(), Leaf()).sub(NodeTypeB(Leaf(), Leaf()))
//res0: NodeTypeA = NodeTypeA(NodeTypeB(Leaf(),Leaf()),Leaf())
```

This has the advantage of returning the correct parent type, `res0: NodeTypeA = ...`, instead of the generic `res0: Traversable = ...`.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. I have considered this approach but prefer not to do it this way because the substitute function is not part of the main codebase. I will not mark this as the answer for now because I am hoping for a different solution. But again thank you for taking the time to answer.